# I want to create a nested conditional program, but it not working how I want it to work and is skipping over other commands

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements, nested

Here is the instruction given to us by our professor. I am a freshman in college and have no idea what I did wrong. Please explain it in the dumbest way you can.

```c
// The Hotel Inn named as On Time Hotel in which you plan to spend the night tonight offers very interesting rates, 
// as long as you do not arrive too late. Housekeeping finishes preparing rooms by noon, and the sooner guests arrive after noon, 
// the less they have to pay. But if the guest arrives earlier, they would need to wait for noon before they can checked-in. 
// Build a C program that calculates your price to pay based on your guest's time of arrival.

// Your program will read an integer (0 to 23) indicating the military hour of your arrival. 
// For example, 12 indicates 12 noon arrival, 13 means 1pm arrival, 0 means midnight arrival, etc. 

// The base price is 1000 pesos, and 200 pesos are added for every hour after noon. 
// Thankfully the total is capped at 2000 pesos, so you'll never have to pay more than that. 
// Your program should print the price (an integer) you have to pay, given the input hour of arrival.

// Additionally, If the client arrives from 6 until 11, then program must ask first whether they are checking-in now.
// If yes, then they must be charged at the capped price. On the other hand.
// If not, then they must be told to wait for 12 noon for check-in.

// Note: If the user entered a float, then it would be read as an integer

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    int time, initial_fee = 1000, late_fee, capped_fee = 2000;
    char y_n; 

    printf("What is the hour of your arrival? ");
    scanf("%i", &time);

    if (time == 12) {
        printf("Please pay %i pesos\n", initial_fee);
    }
    else if (time <= 17 && time >= 13) {
        late_fee = ((time - 12) * 200) + initial_fee;
        printf("Please pay %i pesos\n", late_fee);
    }
    else if (23 >= time && time >= 18) {
        printf("Please pay %i pesos\n", capped_fee);
    }
     else if (5 >= time && time >= 0) {
        printf("Please pay %i pesos\n", capped_fee);
    }
    else if ((11 >= time) && (time >= 6)) {
        printf("Are you checking in now[Y/N]? ");
        scanf(" %c", &y_n);
        if ((y_n == 'Y') && (y_n == 'y')) {
            printf("Please pay %i pesos\n", capped_fee);
        }
        else if ((y_n == 'N') && (y_n == 'n')) {
            printf("Please wait for noon to check-in\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("Invalid Input!\n");
        }
    }    
    else {
        printf("Invalid Input!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting the program to work in a way where it will ask an initial question, if a specific answer is given it will prompt another question, then depending on the answer, there are 3 different possible outputs. Instead, it just works until the second question, then always answers with the response I wrote within else {}.

Comment: Some of your `if` tests are wrong.  For example, `if ((y_n == 'Y') && (y_n == 'y')) {` will always be false, since `y_n` can't be equal to both `'Y'` and `'y'` simultaneously.  Change `&&` to `||`.  Similarly for the test that follows it (for `'N'` and `'n'`).